# Modellinng in node js

Tags: node.js

I have scenario in node api where its receives response from another API and i have to concatenate 2 fields from response and send response for my api.

e.g. Response from another API:

```
[{"fname":"mark","lname":"Bradd"},
 {""fname":"Jordon","lname":"Gibb""} ]
```

Concatenated Response:

```
{"fname":"mark","lname":"Bradd","fullname":"mark Bradd"},
{"fname":"Jordon","lname":"Gibb","fullname" :"Jordon Gibb"}
```

I can loop through response which I am getting but I am not sure how can I create response with concatenated fields.

```
for(var i = 0; i < recv.length; i++) 
{
    var sm=recv[i].fName+ " " + recv[i].lName;
    var person= person.PersonFullName(sm);

} 

//person model code
var PersonFullName = function (data) {
    this.push(data)
}

module.exports = PersonFullName;
```

I was trying to create another object with model but couldn't get success. Can you please let me know how can I achieve this in node.

Comment: can you console.log(PersonFullName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
    var concatenatedResponse = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < recv.length; i++){

      concatenatedResponse.push({"fname" : recv[i].fName, "lname" : recv[i].lName, "fullname" : recv[i].fName + " " + recv[i].lName);

    }
```